# What's the best way to check the first message that's received by the server?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sockets, tcp, protocols

With my tpc server i'm trying to get the first message that's sent by the client. So that the server can determine what the purpose of the data is. Since the server can do multiple things with the data that gets sent from the clients. I was thinking maybe like a Protocol or something basically so that the server knows what the client wants to do.

```
public enum Protocol
        {
            Chat;
            Login;
            Disconnect;

    }
```

I made a Protocol class but i'm sure how I could integrate this with the streamRead.

Comment: What do you mean by "the first message"? TCP doesn't do messages, it's a stream. One Write() call does not necessarily correspond to one Read() call at the other end. **You** will have to implement a framing/application protocol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  //Client
  var c = Protocol.Chat;
  stream.WriteByte((byte)c);

  //Server
  var header = (Protocol)stream.ReadByte();
  switch (header) {
  case Protocol.Chat: //Handle Chat
    break;
  case Protocol.Login: //Handle Login
    break;
  case Protocol.Disconnect: //Handle Disconnect
    break;
  }
```

Comment: How do I do this with UDPClient.Send?

Comment: udpClient.Send (new byte[]{(byte)header}, 1);

Comment: So my receiving on the server end is like this. byte[] bytes = listener.Receive(ref groupEP);
                    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)); But im not sure how to receive the Protocol byte. It seems to be alot harder than the streamWriting and Reading.